# How do I convert a solution to windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, projects-and-solutions

There has to be an easier way than to read the entire source code and check each line against what's compatible from the [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426930%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Suggestions?

Comment: Convert from what kind of solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you mean from a Silverlight solution to a Windows Phone 7 solution? Anyhow, the answer is no - there is no simple / easy migration path. Simply copy the project files into a new WP7 project and start working through the compilation errors.

There is on tool that can help you creat portable code, the [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) which allows you to create assemblies which can be linked to Silverlight, WP7, WPF, XNA solutions. However, the code that you can shae is somewhat limited.